# Count frequency of items in array - without two for loops

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, frequency, counting

Need to know is there a way to count the frequency of items in a array without using two loops. This is without  knowing the size of the array. If I know the size of the array I can use switch without looping. But I need more versatile than that. I think modifying the quicksort may give better results.

```
Array[n];

TwoDArray[n][2];
```

First loop will go on Array[], while second loop is to find the element and increase it count in two-d array.

```
max = 0;
for(int i=0;i<Array.length;i++){

found= false;

for(int j=0;j<TwoDArray[max].length;j++){

if(TwoDArray[j][0]==Array[i]){
TwoDArray[j][1]+=;
found = true;
break;
}
}

if(found==false){
TwoDArray[max+1][0]=Array[i];
TwoDArray[max+1][1]=1;
max+=;
}
```

If you can comment or provide better solution would be very helpful.

Comment: some languages provider higher construct to achieve this, if you are able to use a hashtable you will not need 2 loops

Answer (score 1):

Use map or hash table to implement this. Insert key as the array item and value as the frequency.

Alternatively you can use array too if the range of array elements are not too large. Increase the count of value at indexes corresponding to the array element.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a map keyed by the item in the array and with a value that is the count of that item. One pass over the array to build the map that contains the counts. For each item, look it's count up in the map, increment the count, and put the new count back into the map.

The map put and get operations can be constant time (e.g., if you use a hash map implementation with a good hash function and properly sized backing store). This means you can compute the frequencies in time proportional to the number of elements in your array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is better than using a map or hash table (especially not when there are lots of duplicates, though in that case you can get close to O(n) sorting with certain techniques, so this is not too bad either), it's just an alternative.

- Sort the array
- Use a (single) for-loop to iterate through the sorted array

  - If you find the same element as the previous one, increment the current count
  - If you find a different element, store the previous element and its count and set the count to 1
  - At the end of the loop, store the previous element and its count